# How to set log4j2 folder in tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j2, tomcat8

I'm running a `spring-boot` `war` application in `tomcat8` and use `log4j2` for logging.
Problem:

- the logs are found in the wrong directory
- the logs don't rotate properly

log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
       <Appenders>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="APP" fileName="logs/my-application.log"
                                 filePattern="logs/archive/my-application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.}: %m%n" charset="UTF-8" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
       <Root level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="APP" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Result: the logs are found in `/var/log/tomcat8/my-application.log`. The archives in `/var/log/tomcat8/my-application.log.gz`

This is really strange. The correct logger filenames are picked up. But now the folders.

Question: why is my `/logs` folder not taken into account? And why does the zipped archive name not contain the timestamp?

Sidenote: running the app as a `jar` in my idea works perfectly. It automatically creates a `/logs` folder under the classpath root. And all files are properly moved to `/archive` at midnight, with timestamp!

But why is this not working as is in tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the cause:

If the `fileName` starts without a `/`, it is taken relative to `catalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat8`
Inside that folder is a symlink `/logs`. thus a `fileName="logs/myapp"` will follow that symlink. Which points to `/var/log/tomcat8`.

As a result all files are written into that folder.
Further, some tomcat default `logrotate` seems to take all files inside that folder and automatically compress it. So log4j has no chance to apply the logrotate.

Solution: just set and additional subpath for the filename. I used:

```
fileName="logs/logs/my-application.log"
filePattern="logs/logs/my-app..."
```

This will move the logfiles to:

```
/var/log/tomcat8/logs
/var/log/tomcat8/logs/archive
```